# ajax+json+jquery+datatables+spring mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, datatable

I am looking for a way to populate data inside the datatables but the data is not coming out.
I will show my codes step by step.

This is inside the controller with contains dummies data.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/claim/prApplication",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody DataTablesJsonModel getDataTableSelfClaim(@RequestBody String employeeId){
    HraPrmClaimApplication toShow=new HraPrmClaimApplication();
    toShow.setApplicationId((Integer)1);
    toShow.setDate("2015.01.01");
    toShow.setTotalAmount((double)200);
    toShow.setDocument("sample.pdf");
    toShow.setNote("");
    DataTablesJsonModel toReturn=new DataTablesJsonModel();
    toReturn.setAaData(toShow);
    System.out.print(toReturn);
    return toReturn;
}
```

---

This is inside my jsp page.

```
function loadSelfTable(){
            return initSingleSelectDataTable("#selfTable",null,null,"/",true,
            {
                "sDom": "<'row'<'col-xs-6'i><'col-xs-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-xs-6'i><'col-xs-6'p>>",
                "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/hra/prm/claim/prApplication",    
                "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aaData, fnCallback ) {
                    $.ajax( {
                            dataType: 'json',
                            type: "POST", 
                            url:  sSource,
                            success:function(result){
                                if (result.aaData.code != null && result.aaData.code != '') {
                                    $('#errorMsgPanel > div > span').text(result.aaData.message);
                                    $('#errorMsgPanel').css("display", "block");
                                    fnCallback({aaData:[]});
                                }
                                else {                                                                          
                                    fnCallback(result); 
                                    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
                                }
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert('<fmt:message key="ER0996" bundle="${messageBundle}"/>' + " (textStatus: " + textStatus + " errorThrown: " + errorThrown + " jqXHR.status: " + jqXHR.status + ")");
                        }
                    });
                },
                "aoColumns":[
                                {"mDataProp":"applicationId"},
                                {"mDataProp":"appDate"},
                                {"mDataProp":"amount"},
                                {"mDataProp":"status"},
                                {"mDataProp":"document"},
                                {"mDataProp":"note"},
                            ],
                "aaSorting": [],
            });

        } 

$(document).ready(function(){

                loadSelfTable();

        });
```

My problem is when i alert the result, the data show as a string.
But the data does not populate inside the table.
Help me if you have any ideas how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Put JSON.parse(result) instead of JSON.stringify(result)

You are returning only result. Verify from your controller method that is it generating "application/json" otherwise convert your string to json object.

also change as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/claim/prApplication",method=RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")
```

Comment: Really appreciate your answer but still this one is not making my table populate. :(

Comment: Only change Request Mapping don't change anything else. if it doesn't work then change your fncallbackfunction with fnCallback(JSON.parse(result));

Comment: May I look your initSingleSelectDataTable as you have not written initialization of datatable like:$('#example').dataTable();